# confusion on using functor <$>

Tags: haskell, functor

Why does the code of line

```
generateScripts pb = (greet <$>) <$> (maybeName <$> pb
```

have an extra functor after `greet`? Based on my understanding, I know that the LHS function will be used on the RHS but since there is an extra functor, I don't understand how it works.

```
maybeName :: (String, String) -> Maybe String
maybeName p = if length (snd p) == 10 then Just (fst p) else Nothing

generateScripts :: [(String, String)] -> [Maybe String]
generateScripts pb = (greet <$>) <$> (maybeName <$> pb)
    where greet = ("Hello "++)

phonebook = [ ("Bob",   "0178866524"), ("Fred",  "01624556442"), ("Alice", "0188998533") ]
```

```
GHCi> phonebook = [ ("Bob",   "0178866524"), ("Fred",  "01624556442"), ("Alice", "0188998533") ]
GHCi> generateScripts phonebook
[Just "Hello Bob",Nothing,Just "Hello Alice"]
```

Comment: As a matter of style, I’d probably write this as `fmap greet <$> fmap maybeName pb` to reduce parentheses. You can check the type of a subexpression like `fmap` using a “type wildcard” (`_`), e.g. `(fmap :: _) greet <$> (fmap :: _) maybeName pb`: the compiler will report that the first has type `(a -> b) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b`, the second `(a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`. Also, you can compose the two fmaps into one by the `Functor` law `fmap f . fmap g` = `fmap (f . g)`, which also lets you omit (eta-reduce) the `pb` parameter: `generateScripts = fmap (fmap ("Hello " ++) . maybeName)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(greet <$>)` is a function which apply to each elements of type Maybe String, and the `(greet <$>) <$>` apply to whole List, i.e. [Maybe String], as illustration

```
(greet <$>) <$> (maybeName <$> pb)
= (greet <$>) <$> [Just "Bob", Nothing, Just "Alice"]
= [greet <$> Just "Bob", greet <$> Nothing, greet <$> Just "Alice"]
```

Answer (score 4):

`pb` is a list of `(String, String)` tuples.

`maybeName <$> pb` maps `maybeName` over that list, giving `[Maybe String]` (a list of Maybes). The functor in question is `[]`.

`(greet <$>) <$> ...` maps `(greet <$>)` over that list, i.e. it applies `(greet <$>)` to each element of the list (the elements having type `Maybe String`). The functor in question is `[]`.

`(greet <$>)` maps `greet` over `Maybe String`. The functor in question is `Maybe`.

In general, if you have a function `f :: a -> b`, then `(f <$>) :: (Functor f) => f a -> f b`, and `((f <$>) <$>) :: (Functor f, Functor g) => g (f a) -> g (f b)`. Every `<$>` maps over another layer of functor.

In this case we have `g = []` and `f = Maybe`, so this effectively makes `greet :: String -> String` operate on a structure where strings are nested two levels deep, such as `[Maybe String]`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `<$>` near `greet` is a `fmap` for `Maybe`, that is, it applies `greet` to `x` if the value is `Just x` and does nothing in case of `Nothing`.

So, `maybeName <$> pb` maps `maybeName` function over `pb` list, the `<$>` in the middle maps `greet <$>` over the result and the `greet <$>` itself modifies `Just` values with `greet`.